# COALESCE if no rows exist in table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these two tables:

users (this has an updated_at column) and user_updates (this has a foreign key user_id to users and a created_at column)

I want to find the latest user update for user so I have this:

```
SELECT  user_id, 
        MAX(COALESCE(user_updates.created_at,users.updated_at)) as last_update
FROM user_updates
INNER JOIN users 
    ON users.id = user_updates.user_id
WHERE user_id IN (<user_id>)
GROUP BY user_id
;
```

This works as long as there exists `user_updates` exist for a `user_id`. However, if there are no `user_updates`, I would want to return the `users.updated_at`. How can I change this query?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you need `left join` instead :

```
SELECT u.id, 
       MAX(COALESCE(up.created_at, u.updated_at)) as last_update
FROM users u LEFT JOIN 
     user_updates up 
     ON u.id = up.user_id
WHERE u.id IN (<user_id>)
GROUP BY u.id;
```

Comment: This won't work. Sometimes I don't have user_updates so if it's in the FROM clause it won't work.

Comment: @HommerSmith have you tried it?  A LEFT JOIN implies that the query will return rows for every matching row in `user`, regardless of whether there is a matching row in `user_updates`.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can probably assume that `up.updated_at` is created after the `u.updated_at`, I would write the logic as:

```
SELECT u.id, 
       COALESCE(MAX(up.updated_at), MAX(u.updated_at)) as last_update
FROM users u LEFT JOIN 
     user_updates up 
     ON u.id = up.user_id
WHERE u.id IN (<user_id>)
GROUP BY u.id;
```

This makes it clearer that you want the maximum of the user updates date and if that doesn't exist, then the user date.